# Creating Xen backups

Tags: centos, backup, xen, lvm

I'm looking for a way to create Xen (HVM) backups, using LVM. I know `xm save` but that is a) inefficient space wise, b) the VM will shut down. I found `rsnapshot` which is able to create an LVM snapshot, but to restore this I will have to copy all files over to the machine (instead of just restoring the complete LVM, everything seems to be individual files).

Is there any backup software you recommend? I'm running CentOS on my Xen host. Some requirements:

- It can be paid software but not too expensive (personal use)
- It should have differential (like a full backup, then an incremental backup (to preserve space)).
- Easy to restore the Xen VM (currently `rsnapshot` needs to copy all files over, instead of one `.img` file to restore or something similar).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What HVM machines are running there? Is NTFS involved?

Comment: `xm save` will make a memory snapshot. So it is not what you are searching for. BTW - there is an option to let the DomU run. See `xm help save`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for personal use I would recommend to

1. Snapshot the LV (an LV corresponds to a DomU-disk, I assume?)
2. Make a full copy of that LV into a Backup-LV of the same size

If it is a Linux filesystem you can just use `mkfs` and then do an rsync from the RO-mounted source to the RW-mounted target.

If it is NTFS use the NTFS-tools described at [CentOS.org](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/NTFS).

Comment: I'm thinking of using `dd` of a LVM snapshot, and gzipping it. I wont have incremental backups then, but since I use multiple operating systems I can not use your method.

Comment: I tried `dd` with an **XP LV** but was not able to boot it afterwards. So try a restore to be sure that it will work.